# ffmpeg recording 16 bits even if I want only 8 bits

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried following commands:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -sample_fmt u8 -ac 1 -ar 11025 -i audio="mic" output.wav
ffmpeg -f dshow -sample_fmt u8p -ac 1 -ar 11025 -i audio="mic" output.wav
```

Every time I try to get 8 bits output ffmpeg returns 16 bits per sample.

Is there any way to record with 8 bits per sample?

Answer (score 1):

Default encoder for WAV output is pcm_s16le (PCM signed 16-bit little-endian). Use one of these encoders:

| encoder | description |
| --- | --- |
| pcm_s8 | PCM signed 8-bit |
| pcm_s8_planar | PCM signed 8-bit planar |
| pcm_u8 | PCM unsigned 8-bit |

Example:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -channels 1 -sample_rate 11025 -i audio="mic" -c:a pcm_u8 output.wav
```

- I changed the input options to use the [documented dshow options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#dshow).
- See `ffmpeg -encoders` for a list of encoders.

Comment: I already recorded 8bits sounds with NAudio BUT the result was a lot of noice. That is most probable reason that ffmpeg would not allow to record 8bit samples. The only good solution to this would be encode WAV with 8 bits so the noice would be eliminated.

Comment: @joshjoyer Seems orthogonal to the original question. Does the answer not do as you asked?

Comment: your answer is very good BUT the final answer should be broadened over fact that It is not possible to record 8bit with ffmpeg because it would give much noice. So the best solution would be to record 32bits per sample (that is possible in contrast to 8bits which is not) and latter convert it to 8bits if needed (especially when sending data over internet)

Comment: @joshjoyer It's up to the input device to provide the sample bit depth. You can add the `-c:a pcm_u8` input option if you want to force usage of the pcm_u8 decoder if you are convinced the device outputs PCM unsigned 8-bit. Noise can indicate many things including incorrect sample format.